# Smoothing a probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $P$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R^k$ which not necessarily admits a PDF with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

I would like to construct a sequence of probability measures $Q_n$ which approximate $P$ with the following properties:

- $Q_n\to P$ weakly.
- Each $Q_n$ admits a PDF $q_n$.
- The PDF is everywhere strictly positive: $q_n(x) > 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

I suspect that if $\mathcal N(0,I_k/n)$ is the multivariate normal distribution, then the convolution $Q_n = \mathcal N(0, I_k/n) * P$ *may* have all required properties, but I have not seen the full proof (although the smoothness property can be deduced using [these notes](http://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/381/Convolutions-Smoothing.pdf) and weak convergence should not be hard to prove).

Could you point me to references which study this or similar problems?

*Edit*: as @geetha290krm observed, requiring that $Q_n\to P$ strongly is not feasible when $P$ does not admit a PDF.

Comment: If $Q_n$ has pdf for each $n$ and $Q_n(A) \to P(A)$ for all $A$ then $P$ has pdf.

Comment: Think in terms of random variables. If $X \sim P$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$ then $X+\frac Y n \to X$ a.s..

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great observation! Could you suggest a reference studying properties of the convolutions with normal distributions? I was thinking that adding this small independent normal noise (exactly from your second comment) is a good way of obtaining nicely-behaving approximations of probability measures, but now I see that the problem is more complex...